# How can $I$ became ideal in $R=Z[X]$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Suppose $I$ be the collection of polynomials of degree atleast 2 together with the zero polynomial of the ring $R=Z[X]$
,as for an ideal $I$ if $a,b\in I$ then $a+b\in I$
my doubt is that if i choose $p(x)=x^2+x+5$and $q(x)=-x^2+1$ then
$p(x)+q(x)=x+6 \notin I$
so $I$ is not closed under addition
then how $I$ beacme ideal of $R$?

But in Dummit and Foote book, the author claims I an ideal. How ?( I attached the screenshot)[image]

Comment: How are you defining $I$? If the ideal contains $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ then, by definition, $x+6$ will be in $I$.

Comment: but x+6 is of degree 1 then how it belongs to $I$ as $I$ is the collection of polynoimals degree at least 2( that means degree of  $0$ and degree of $1$ not in $I$)

Comment: $I$ is not an ideal here, for exactly the reason you have given as it must be a subgroup of $R$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The polynomials $p(x) = x^2 + x + 5$ and $q(x) = -x^2 + 1$ do not belong to the ideal $I$, because they have terms of degree less than 2. Note that $I$ is *not* the set of polynomials of degree at least 2; it is the set of polynomials that do not have *terms* of degree 0 or 1. In other words, $I$ is the set of all polynomials of the form
$$ a_n x^n + a_{n-1} x^{n-1} + \cdots + a_3 x^3 + a_2 x^2, $$
where $n \geq 2$, together with the zero polynomial.